# WinCE and SqlServerCE database Connection

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-ce

Dose windows mobile 6 SDK support sqlserverce database operations into MFC smart device application?
I can create database on sqlserverce using COM components, but I dont want to use it instead will prefer windows mobile 6 SDK.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the WinMo SDK have to do with it?  SQL Compact is a separate thing shipped outside of the SDKs.  Interacting with SQL CE from C++ is done through set of [OLEDB interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174142(v=SQL.100).aspx).  If you're asking if you can use the [CEDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee489973.aspx) or [EDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee490587.aspx) APIs for interaction with a SQL Compact database, then the answer is "no."

Comment: Previously I was trying hard to connect to SQLCE database using SDK. I did it through EDB APIs. Thank you for clearing doubts....